# Python not importing functions from module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

So, I have this project of a form similar to this:

```
./
./__init__.py
./main.py
./errorHandle.py
./functions.py
```

Now, In my main.py I have this:

```
import errorHandling
from functions import *
```

And in errorHandle.py:

```
from functions import sendMessage
def exceptionHandle(ex,errorCode):
   def exceptionHandle(ex,errorCode):
print(ex)
extra = ""
status = 1
if errorCode == constants.ErrorCodes.aws:
    constants.awsWorking = 0
    if checkConnection() == True:
        extra = "A network connection was detected but no connection to AWS was possible. Possibilities include an issue of authentication, renamed/incorrectly named shadow, or a duplicate client name. "
        constants.errorsListDelayed[int(time.time())] = [ex,errorCode,extra,constants.TargetConnection.aws]
    else:
        extra = "No internet connection detected/Google DNS down. "
        constants.errorsListDelayed[int(time.time())] = [ex,errorCode,extra,constants.TargetConnection.awsAndMail]
        return
elif errorCode == constants.ErrorCodes.loadConfig:
    extra = checkIniExists()
elif errorCode == constants.ErrorCodes.camera:
    status, extra = checkCameraInitial()
elif errorCode == constants.ErrorCodes.loadImages:
    extra= "Couldn't load images. "
else:
    extra= "Unknown Error location"
if status == 1:
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
sendErrorMessage(ex,errorCode,extra)
uploadError(ex,errorCode)
```

(indentation got a bit messy after copying)

And in my functions I have a number of functions, including the aforementioned sendMessage

Now, for some reason while I am able to import errorHandle, none of its functions, including the exceptionHandle function show, but it IS importing, as I can do something like this fine:

```
errorHandle.sendMessage(...)
```

And it would work without any real issues

I have also attempted different imports, with different errors that more or less resulted in the same idea. So I tried:

```
from errorHandle import exceptionHandle
```

But that didn't work either.

I have also tried

```
from errorHandle import *
```

which just loaded sendMessage only, and I tried to change the code in errorHandle to change the sendMessage to *, which loaded all the functions.py files, and I tried removing the whole import functions from errorHandle.py, which changed nothing.

Kind-of lost here, since it IS importing the module and recognizing it, just not the functions in the module.

EDIT:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'exceptionHandle' from 'errorHandling'
```

I have ensured all the names are correct, also no functions exist with either of those names, I have also tried different names to make sure its not a weird bug due to a certain name.

Comment: How are you getting `ImportError: cannot import name 'exceptionHandle' from 'errorHandling'` when you specify `errorHandle`? Where is that extra `ing` coming from? Do you have any symlinks in your directory?

Comment: That is a typo when I wanted to show the error, as I tried a few different names. As for symlinks, considering I don't know what they are, I think its unlikely.

Comment: I suspect that while trying a few different names, you used the wrong ones.

Comment: I might've done so, but the main issue is still there with the correct name. I can run the older code to see if the error here changes in some time.

Comment: Sorry, but i copy-pasted the code you have shown and it is working fine (giving no errors). Cannot reproduce. There must be a typo somewhere.

Comment: _Wait_ : have you got real code for that exceptionHandle function, or is there really an ellipsis (`...`) ?

Comment: Is there anything in either of the modules themselves that can cause this error then? Because both modules are full of code, and I am not sure how a type would cause the module to be loaded, just not all the functions.

Comment: Yes, I have the code for it. Let me update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you by any chance have a function named `errorHandle` inside your functions.py file?

Please see the code I have, and that it is running. Can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so the bug/problem can be replicated.

```
user@Inspiron:~/code/general/remthisdir$ cat errorHandle.py ;echo;cat functions.py ;echo ;cat main.py 
from functions import sendMessage
def exceptionHandle():
    print('Inside exceptionHandle')

def sendMessage():
    print('Inside sendMessage')

import errorHandle
from functions import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    errorHandle.exceptionHandle()
    sendMessage()
user@Inspiron:~/code/general/remthisdir$ python main.py 
Inside exceptionHandle
Inside sendMessage
user@Inspiron:~/code/general/remthisdir$
```

Comment: I am unsure of how to get a better example here because other modules are loading fine (e.g. function), and I have many other modules in the program which I didnt include as they have no other relationship with this issue, I have this issue even when deleting every other function under errorHandling.py. So I am unsure.

Comment: My recommendation would be to first keep just three files having the two functions (with just pass in their definition) in a new dir to see if you get the error. And then keep pasting everything else.

Comment: Fair enough, Let me try that and will get back when I have an update.

Comment: I have upvoted your answer and will accept it, the issue was due to another import causing issues, which I will need to investigate but that's a seperate issue I will check. Can't believe something as simple as just deleting everything and adding it one by one escaped my mind. Thanks!